# Mounting Shared Folders in domain using Active Directory Authentication at login

Tags: mount, active-directory, likewise

I have Windows Server 2008 set up with AD. Have set up the group policies to map two communal folders and a user folder (the user folder using a logon script). I've joined the Ubuntu machine to the Domain and can access the shares and mount them, but would like to mount them when the user logs on.

I know it's possible to put the username and password in fstab but would like to just use AD as it does when navigating through the files. Is creating a `.smbcredentials` file for each user the only option?

Also, I'm using [Likewise Open](http://www.likewise.com/products/likewise_open/) to authenticate.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)